# js getHours() returning time +5 hours ahead

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm trying to get my local Hour with getHours(), but it is returning a time that is 5 hours in the future.

```
var today = new Date();
var curHr = today.getHours();
```

When I console log curHr, it says the value is 18, but I'm on the east coast and it's currently 1pm (expecting value 13).  Am I missing something?

Update-
It is indeed returning UTC, but I've checked my computer settings and everything and the times do not match:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please console.log() both declared values and paste in question? I believe the timezone is probably set wrong in Windows but you may have manually set time.

Comment: Could you also do a `console.log(today.toString())`, to see what Timezone it thinks it's in

Comment: You are getting UTC, arent you?

Comment: I assume you've already checked your computer's time and timezone settings?

Comment: yea I've checked my computer's time settings and it is correct, but it's still returning UTC

Comment: Does your computer have the correct time zone set?

Comment: yea, it shows (UTC -05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

Comment: What browser are you using (including version)?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.  I'm using Chrome v. 77.0.3865.120

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var today = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}));
var curHr = today.getHours();
```